# Eclipse plugin file use

Tags: eclipse, file, plugins, filepath

In my Eclipse plugin, I need to use a file from package explorer. I click on a file with right mouse button and select "View" (my plugin name). So, how can I reach this file path in my plugin project?

http://i49.tinypic.com/2j29ifs.png

I have this:

```
public class ViewHandler extends AbstractHandler {
...
 public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException { 
 ...
 ...
        URI uri = null;
        try {
            test();
            uri = URI.createURI("../models/task.cm");
            Resource resource = resourceSet
                    .getResource(uri, true);
            Model model = (Model) resource.getContents().get(0);
            ModelExtractor showModel = new ModelExtractor(model);
            showModel.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And I need to replace this line:
     `uri = URI.createURI("../models/task.cm");`

with relative path to file.

Or if you have some good tuto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Command Handler (I hope, you are using the Command Framework, not JFace Actions) you could check for the currently selected element, and then use the resulting IFile for parsing.

Comment: Use the utility methods of the HandlerUtil class. First idea is HandlerUtil.getSelection(), there you get the ISelection representatation of the selection, and from that you can get the IFile.

Comment: But I'm using AbstractHandler
    `public class ViewHandler extends AbstractHandler {`
and there is no getSelection() method in your HandlerUtil...

Comment: Indeed, I was writing getSelection() instead of getCurrentSelection(). I did not have Eclipse open when I was writing the answer. The AbstractHandler is all right.

Comment: Okey, I've got this:
     `ISelection select = HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection(event);`
but I can't retype this "select" to IFile or IPath. And if I type only 
     `select.toString();`
it writeout
     `[L/cz.cvut.earlgrey.classmodel/model/task.cm]`
but i don't want there these [ ] and I don't want to use substrings or something like that.

Comment: Retype your ISelection to IStructuredSelection, and then you can iterate over the selected elements (in your case probably IFiles).